# Editing a bot's message just like when you swipe a page, discord.py

Tags: discord.py, message, editing

I wanted to make a command that edits the bot's old message trought another command, example:

```
user: !cmds
bot: *commands list*

user: !next
bot: *edits old message into a new one*
```

I have tried many times to make it myself, but I failed all the times, can anyone help me?

How I tried to make it:

```py
@client.command
async def test():
  embed=discord.Embed(title="Page1")
  await ctx.send(embed=embed)

@client.event
async def on_command(message):
    embed2=discord.Embed(title="Page2")
    await client.process_commands(message)
    if message.content == '$next':
        await message.edit(content=embed2)
```

Comment: Please add a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), SO is not a site were we write code for others

Comment: Ok, sorry, I tried to make it like this:

```@client.command
async def test():
  embed=discord.Embed(title="Page1")
  await ctx.send(embed=embed)

@client.event
async def on_command(message):
    embed2=discord.Embed(title="Page2")
    await client.process_commands(message)
    if message.content == '$next':
        await message.edit(content=embed2)```

Answer (score 0):

The `on_command` event is called whenever a command is called, you didn't register a `next` command, that's one, second of all `on_command` doesn't take `message` argument, it takes the `Context`(`ctx`).

An idea to make what you're asking for is having a cog with an instance variable that references to the previous message, then edit it when the `next` command is called.

```py
class SomeCog(commands.Cog):
    def __init__(self, client):
        self.client = client
        self._previous_message = None


    @commands.command()
    async def test(self, ctx):
        message = await ctx.send("I'll edit this message when you type `$next`")
        self._previous_message = message


    @commands.command()
    async def next(self, ctx):
        if self._previous_message is None: # Exiting if the `test` command wasn't called before, i.e the message is a NoneType
            return await ctx.send("You need to invoke first `$test`")

        await self._previous_message.edit(content="Edited the message")


client.add_cog(SomeCog(client))
```

I'm guessing you could do it with global or bot vars but this is the best way to do it, in my opinion.